# Raspberry pi code times out after a few minutes of running

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a sonar sensor on a bread board connected to raspberry pi. My goal is every time something goes in front of the sensor it send a file to firebase. My code runs fine but it times out after a few minutes of running. Is there a way to restart program or how could I change the code to fix the problem.

I have tried to make it always send data to the server. Even when something dosen't cross in front of it. I have tried only when it does cross in front of it and it still doesn't work.

```
import pyrebase
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

x = 0
y = 0
while y < 1:
config = {
    "apiKey": "x",
    "authDomain": "x",
    "databaseURL": "x",
     "storageBucket": "x",
     "serviceAccount": "x"
    }

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

'''
initialize app with config
'''

'''
    authenticate a user
'''


auth = firebase.auth()

user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("email@gmail.com", "no")

db = firebase.database()

'''
    Create using push
'''
data = { "name" : "Joe Tilsed" }
archer = {"name": "Sterling Archer", "agency": "Figgis Agency"}
db.child("agents").push(archer, user['idToken'])

pam = {"name": "Pam Poovey", "agency": "Figgis Agency"}

while x < 1:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    TRIG = 18
    ECHO = 24

    GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)


    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == False:
            start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == True:
            end = time.time()
    sig_time = end-start

    distance = sig_time / 0.000148

    #print('d:{} in'.format(distance))



    if distance < 9:
        if distance > 1:
            db.child("today").push (data, user['idToken']),
            db.child("month").push (pam, user['idToken']),
            db.child("year").push (pam, user['idToken']),
            db.child("week").push (pam, user['idToken'])
        #else:
            #db.child("month").push (pam, user['idToken']),
```

Comment: `try catch` in `while block`?

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: If you cannot find which code is error , `try cat` is better solution.

Comment: Which version of `python` are you running here?

Comment: I see you have commented out the `print()`. Did your program show the `distance` variable being repeatedly printed?

Comment: @quamrana I did because I needed to determine the minimum and maximum distance for the sonar

Comment: @SovietFrontier the latest version I believe. Python 3

Comment: I'm just wondering whether it all works (just printing the distance) without connecting to firebase. This is just to try to diagnose one problem at a time.

Comment: better suited on raspberry pi site

Comment: @quamrana I am currently running it where it just keeps printing out the distance and it stopped after 2 minutes and 13 seconds

Comment: Does it just stop printing, or does the program exit (with a stack trace?)

Comment: @quamrana stops printing but program keeps running because its at 25% even tho its not printing

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a [similar project](https://github.com/astpierre/astpier-ece40862), hooking a temp sensor up to a raspberry pi zero and sending data to Firebase. In my experience, the script stopped running when the temp sensor was not soundly connected to the GPIO pins. I ended up soldering my leads to the temp sensor to the raspberry pi and that seemed to fix it.

Alternatively, you could put the contents of the while loop in a try clause and catch the exception thrown by the script causing it to exit.

Comment: my problem is I have to run it with wires from the top of the recycling bin to the bottom where the raspberry pi and bread board are

Comment: If the wires are not pressed against the GPIO pads, the script stopped working. Even gently touching the raspberry pi causes the script to halt for me.